# JQuery DataTable Add Row with empty textbox

Tags: jquery, datatables

In JQuery Datatable plugin, i have populated some data.

Now i need to add a new empty row with empty textboxes below the existing dataTable rows.

I tried using the below code piece, its adding the row as undefined

```
$('#eventTable').DataTable().row.add([
            counter + '.1',
            counter + '.2',
            counter + '.3',
            counter + '.4',
            counter + '.5',
            counter + '.5',
            counter + '.5'
    ]).draw(false);
```

Is there is any way to add a new empty row with text boxes.

Comment: value of `counter` is ?

Comment: Why not create a codepen or jsfiddle? You might solve the problem whilst doing this, and if not people can see your datatable and help fix whatever is going wrong